# basic_string_view<SomeClass>

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, string-view

Is there any downside to using `basic_string_view<T>` where `T` is not a trivial type, and not even a POD?  This construct compiled and seemed to work.

I am looking for a read-only view into `vector<T>`.  `span` is unavailable because we don't use C++20.

Comment: The standard requires (**[string.view]/1**) that the template argument to `basic_string_view` be a char-like type. **[strings.general]** defines a char-like type as any non-array POD type.

Comment: I highly recommend [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library, which is the origin of C++20 Ranges library.